# globally installed npm-packages not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, coffeescript, npm

local npm-packages work as predicted, but it seems impossible for me to get globally-installed packages running. It doesn't even throw any error, it's just not doing anything ( express, coffee, etc.. )

This was not bothering me much until I wanted to use coffee-script.

things I allready checked ( I'm on Xubuntu 12.04 ):

- npm lists it
- its installed in /usr/local/bin
- ( updated | uninstalled | reinstalled ) npm via  ( npm | apt-get )
- uninstalled nodejs and did fresh git-rebuild to /opt/bin/node

  => same thing..

anyone knows a solution?

Comment: Do you install them via `sudo npm install -g <name>`?

Comment: Doesn't matter if sudo npm install -g <name> or <name> -g -> it does get installed but if i try the package terminal commands  nothing happens

Comment: You might have made the same mistake I did. In debian, there are two packages with node in the name (node and nodejs), node is not related to nodejs but if you happen to install it, it conflicts with nodejs. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/235655/node-js-conflicts-sbin-node-vs-usr-bin-node

Answer (score 7, accepted):

turns out it tried to start with `node` instead of `nodejs` command. So in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee` I changed `#!/usr/bin/env node` to `#!/usr/bin/env nodejs` and works fine now.

Comment: This solved some of my problems. Wish I found your solution earlier. Been struggling for about a week now :(

Comment: @tibtob, can you tell me how you debugged that? TIA

Comment: Unfortunately didn't solve my issue, still the same symptoms after changing node to nodejs

Comment: good day, I know this answer was posted a very long time ago, I need help if you may, where is /usr/local btw? Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

is `NODE_PATH` variable set on your environment

```
//show if set
echo $NODE_PATH

//set NODE_PATH
NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"
```

The `NODE_PATH` should contain the location of directories where the modules are installed. It can have multiple directories (colon seperated).

Comment: $NODE_PATH was not set, but thanks to you i checked out the node_modules-folder again :)

Comment: and what did that do @tibtob,  i use arch linux, didnt know there was a node path.

Comment: In windows you can find the path to be set using the command 'where node'. Set the NODE_PATH env variable to this folder.