# How to get cleaver (slideshow maker) work in my console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I would like to use [Cleaver](https://github.com/jdan/cleaver) for a presentation. I followed the authors' instructions, which are:

Get it on NPM:

> npm install -g cleaver

And run it like so:

> cleaver path/to/something.md

Problem: Bash seems to recognize Cleaver as a registered program, but when processed with a markdown file, it doesn't seem produce any presentation, the prompt just accepts the command and no output is produced. Would be glad if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Does your current user have write perms to path/to/something?  It should simply write an html file by default, so perhaps it simply can't write to the destination.

Comment: I do not think that is the case, I tried `sudo` + the cleaver command, still didn't work.

Comment: That's definitely odd.  You also checked both the current pwd and the path/to/something for the output?

Comment: Infact the command `cleaver` is consumed just like that by bash and it doesn't produce any results, like help text. So I wonder if the package available online is a working release.

Comment: or maybe you have some other cleaver executable on your path?

Comment: yes I checked the path. I tried absolute path too. No help.

Comment: If cleaver is not in the path, bash would throw an error, right?

Comment: Yeah.  I tend to have the opposite problem with npm -g on my mac in that I have to manually symlink the node_module bin to my sbin path.  And if you are even doing an absolute path than for sure it's acting up. So I am stumped!

Comment: I did not add anything to the path variable, bash consumes the command, so I assume its in path. I was talking about the path/to/something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved when the shebang was changed from `#!/usr/bin/env node` to  `#!/usr/bin/env nodejs`

courtesy:
[globally installed npm-packages not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843199/globally-installed-npm-packages-not-working)