# Can't install gulp on windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm busy learning Laravel and in the process trying to install gulp.

Operating system: Windows 10

In the command line:
npm -v gives: 2.15.2
node -v gives: v4.4.5

Then I tried all kinds of ways I found on the internet to install gulp, all give me a cursor that keeps rotating and nothing happens.

What I tried:

npm install -g gulp

npm install gulp -g

npm install --global gulp-cli

I also tried:
npm config set proxy false
npm cache clean

That didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Is `NODE_PATH` set in your environment variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843199/globally-installed-npm-packages-not-working)

Comment: You should check your windows firewall configuration, and look if npm is allowed to connect to internet.

Comment: The node path was not in the environment variables. I added it now, but which of the 3 commands should I use?

Comment: Restarted my computer. Windows Firewall is switched off. Avast Antivirus switched off. Tried all 3 again, still hanging.

Comment: I reinstalled node. I checked my npmrc file, it only has this in it: prefix=${APPDATA}\npm

I checked my PATH environment, the TEMP pointed to to places, changed it to: c:\tmp Nothing helps, still hanging.

Answer (score 2):

This also worked for me too:

```
npm install gulp -g -verbose
```

add `--verbose` for another package if you need to, and if it's still not working, maybe you must install package to global first by adding `-g`, and after that, install in your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, this is worked for me.
installed gulp globally : `npm install gulp -g`  and I
had to add npm installation directory.

C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\npm;

To my system path in my environment variables

Answer (score -2):

Finally!!!, this worked: npm install gulp -g -verbose