# Problems installing GULP on Windows 10 as a limited user

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am trying to install gulp on my development Windows 10 Pro machine and it is not working. I have installed node.js and when I use my admin account I can run gulp. However, when I am not an admin, Windows cannot find the library.

Additional details:

1. I have looked at [Can't install gulp on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547755/cant-install-gulp-on-windows-10) and have searched the web with no luck.
2. Using Visual Studio 2015 and the project uses gulp to generate css sass and minify js files.
3. When I run `npm install gulp -g -verbose` I get (eventually) the following output:

[image: Command Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning `npm` cache. use

```
npm cache clean
```

And if that doesn't work try installing `gulp` locally just for that project.

```
npm install gulp
```

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you provided, there is one line where is written that you have not correctly created json file. 
`package.json should be actual JSON not JavaScript`
can you provide your package.json file?

Comment: Well looking at the file in explorer the file size is 0KB. and opening the file in notepad the file is empty. So I guess the string_decoder module did not install correctly.